# Extra space between NavigationBar and TableView

Tags: swift, tableview, navigationbar, spacing, ios13

Getting space between navigation Bar and tableview in latest iOS 13 release? tried many solutions. no luck? please help me in this. 
Tried below solutions

1.

```
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
```

2.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

            tblView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        } else {
            automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }
}
```

3.

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

4.

```
yourtableView.tableHeaderView?.removeFromSuperview()

yourtableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))

yourtableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: is this problem only on iOS 13? Did you try to simulate it on iOS 12?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 2 things :

1.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

2.
   From attribute inspector, make style = plain

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution it worked for me in `iOS 15`:

```swift
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```